# Dahua IPC-HDBW1230E-0280B default password

Tags: ip-camera

I've connected the IPC to NVR and it automatically initialized an IPC. 
I founded, that an IPC have set a default password and I don't know what the password is.
So I cannot initialize and set new admin's password, because an IPC is initialized yet.

Any ideas how to found a password? Thank you.

Comment: https://dahuawiki.com/IPCamera/Change_Username_or_Password

Comment: password is not admin it is 8 letters length

Comment: Solution is that the password is the same I set up on NVR.

Comment: But I have another problem, when I connect IPC to PC I cannot open it via browser only via config tool but its not working.